# jQuery Mobile POST request with multiple pages response

Tags: jquery-mobile

From the documentation, http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

> It's important to note that if you are linking from a mobile page that was loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages, you need to add a **rel="external"** or **data-ajax="false"** to the link. This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash between these two modes.

Now, that seems to only apply to GET requests (i.e. via link elements). However, what is the guideline for POST requests? Right now, for the project I am currently working on, if I make a POST request with response that contains multiple N internal pages (lots of divs with data-role="page" and unique IDs), jQuery mobile only loads the first one it sees, and ignores the rest.

I am pulling my hairs out, not sure what to do to work around this. Is there a way to force jQuery mobile to do to full page reload?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that data-ajax will work just fine inside the form tag. i.e

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">...</form>
```

Previously, I thought I had set data-ajax="false". However, it turns out that with the PHP framework (yii) I use, there is a big difference between "data-ajax" => false and "data-ajax" => "false" (former assigns to boolean type, and later is string type). Anyway, long story short, data-ajax is indeed the solution.